# Run javascript inside imacros

Tags: javascript, proxy, macros, imacros

I'm making a bot with imacros in the form of a .js file. I make it as a javascript file because it's easier when checking text, looping and errorchecking.

Now the problem gets a little messy. I'm trying to click a button using javascript while proxy is being used. Here is my script:

```
var imacros = "PROXY ADDRESS = 12.3.4.5:67" + "\n";
imacros += "EVAL(\"document.getElemensByClassName('class_here')[0].click()\")"
iimPlayCode(imacros);
```

When I try running this, I get error 901.
Why don't I just run it as plain javascript, not as "eval"?
Because at the moment the imacros script stops running, the proxy is gone. and it wouldn't be clicking that button using a proxy.
I've tried, and can't click the button using imacros.

Any help is appreciated. I just want to click that button in javascript while using proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by means of pseudo-URL:

```
var imacros = "PROXY ADDRESS=12.3.4.5:67" + "\n";
imacros += "URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElemensByClassName('class_here')[0].click();undefined;}" + "\n";
iimPlayCode(imacros);
```

Comment: That's what I tried too. Thanks.
Note for anyone that comes reading, that you need to use <SP> instead of space or you will get URL error

Answer (score 0):

You can run external javascript store in local js file
your main macro file main.js

```
var macro = "PROXY ADDRESS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port\n";
immPlayCode(macro);
loadScriptFromURL('file:///F:/imacros/doauto.js');
do_auto();
function loadScriptFromURL(url) { 
/*
...code to load script from your url ...
for examples visit my website http://wirecellar.com/2FJZ
*/
}
```

AND file doauto.js:

```
function do_auto() {/*......*/}
```